# Virtualbox - Setup network for hotspot

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian

I'm running a debian instance via virtualbox on my MacBook. This VM has the local ip 192.168.0.69.

If I'm connected via my cable wlan I can ssh into the VM. But when I'm using the internet hotspot of my Android phone, I cannot even ping the VM. But the internet is working in general.

This behaviour makes no sense to me. In my virtualbox I have enabled the network adapter and have set the following configurations:

```
attached to: Bridged Adapter
Name: en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
Promiscuous Mode: Deny
Cable Connected: Checked
```

This is my interfaces (/etc/network/interfaces) setup:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.69
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem was to setup a host only network following this tutorial:
http://gregk.me/2010/working-on-vm-server-while-offline/